# ¿SE PUEDE USAR DOS ACCION EN UN FORM CON HTML?

Tags: java, html, mysql

Como están, la inquietud que tengo es la siguiente. Estoy elaborando un sistema de matriculación en Java y para la creación de la interfaz utilizo HTML; lo que necesito es que a partir de un mismo form en la parte de HTML, según el rol que cumpla la persona (estudiante o docente) se redireccione a su interfaz que corresponde. La inquietud es ¿Puedo colocar de esta manera
`<form action="docente_srv?accion=Verificar" action="estudiante_srv?accion=Verificar" method="POST"`
para ejecutar lo que quiero? o como puedo hacerlo para que se me ejecute. Agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Lo puedes hacer de muchas formas, por ejemplo, usando javascript. Un ejemplo sería definir el form en javascript con let form = document.getElementById("form"); habiendo primero definido su id y luego crear un listener con form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { e.preventDefault(); funcion1(); funcion2(); }); y ya define funcion1 y funcion2 con lo que quieras. Tienes un ejemplo aquí: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript/

Comment: muy amable por tu ayuda. Lo voy a aplicar y espero que sea lo que busco. Gracias por tu ayuda.